# Is Cordova Bluetooth plugin + HTML5 a good platform for Bluetooth development?

Tags: html, cordova, bluetooth

In evaluating a platform for Bluetooth, and HTML5, research indicates there is a cordova plugin, that can interface with Bluetooth devices. So, in essence, using HTML5 one could use detect Bluetooth devices
and sync with them for data, using these plugins. For instance, if one needed a picture to be downloaded 
from a bluetooth device, it could be done after detecting the device using HTML5. Or, for instance one 
could get GPS coordinates using such connectivity to a Blutooth device. The HTML5 code resides on either
a mobile device, and this handshakes with a Bluetooth device for data, using the cordova Bluetooth plugin. Is this architecture workable in the real world?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cordova could be a workable solution for this problem. However it totally depends on your needs.

If you will only use the features that the Bluetooth plugin of Cordova provides, it will work perfectly with your app. But when in the future your app will need features of Bluetooth that the plugin does not provide, it will be hard to use them because you will need to create your own plugin or request the new features to the developers of the plugin.